# a button for getting data from sql

Tags: php, html

i have create two table in my databases, 1.loginacc (stay login information(LoginID , Password and Permission)2.borrow (have book that the login borrowed,userid)

below is the code: and i have get all the user id,beside every user that i get from database loginacc ,it has a button called 'get information'.when i click it,it will have order of" select * from borrow where userid = (the loginid that shown out )

```
<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

  mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

  $sql = "Select LoginID , Password , Permission
          from loginacc where Permission = 1 ";


  $results = mysql_query($sql,$con);



  echo "<tr><th>Admin</th></tr>";

  echo "<table border=5 cellpadding=10>";
  echo "<tr><th></th><th>ac</th><th>pw</th><th>per</th><th></th></tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 

    echo "<tr><td><form action='searchtable.php' method='get'><button type='button' name='button2' value='button2'>get information</button></td>

    <td><input type=text id='row0' name='row0' value='$row[0]' /></td><td><input type=text id='row1' name='row1' value='$row[1]' /></td>
              <td><input type=text id='row2' name='row2' value='$row[2]' /></td><td><input type='submit' name='button' value='change' /></td></tr>";

  }

  echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use anchor (link) to send the loginID rather than using button , it will be simple . As far as i've understood your problem , you can do it as below .

```
  echo "<table border=5 cellpadding=10>";
  echo "<tr><th></th><th>ac</th><th>pw</th><th>per</th><th></th></tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { 

    echo "<tr><td>
    <a href='searchtable.php?lid=$row[0]'>get information</a></td>

    <td><input type=text id='row0' name='row0' value='$row[0]' /></td><td><input type=text id='row1' name='row1' value='$row[1]' /></td>
              <td><input type=text id='row2' name='row2' value='$row[2]' /></td><td><input type='submit' name='button' value='change' /></td></tr>";

  }

  echo "</table>";
```

Now in the next page i.e. searchtable.php, just get that id using GET method and execute the query . This should be somehow like ,

```
<?php
    $loginId = $_GET['lid'];

    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","password");

  mysql_select_db("babytradeapps");

  $sql = "Select * from borrow where userid = $loginId";    

  $results = mysql_query($sql,$con);
  $final_result = mysql_fetch_array($results);
  print_r($final_result);
  // Manipulate view with the result 

?>
```